# oracle unimplemented feature error while inserting

Tags: oracle, plsql

i have a object type header_o

```
create or replace type header_o as object(
col1 number, 
col2 number, 
col3 number);
```

Then i create a table:

```
create table tab1(
id number, 
header header_o, 
ins_date date);
```

I have a procedure that assigns values to a record.

```
create or replace package pck1
as 
type t_header is record(
col1 number,
col2 number, 
col3 number);
end;
```

here goes package body

```
create or replace package body pck1 is
procedure proc1 is
l_header t_header;
begin
l_header.col1:=1;
l_header.col2:=2;
l_header.col3:=3;
insert into tab1(header) values l_header;
end;
end;
```

So i get error on insert statement while compiling; ORA-03001:unimplemented feature.
the thing is when i create table without columns "id" and "ins_date" the insert works fine:
can anyone tell me where is the mistake, or is it impossible to do so? 

 my oracle version is 11gR2

Comment: It seems to work if you define `l_header` as `header_o`. What do you need `t_header` for?

Comment: @PeterLang  and that is the answer to my question. Yet i have no logical answer to yours. thanks:))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this as an answer since it has solved the problem:

Do not define another type (`t_header`) but declare `l_header` as `header_o` and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the missing brackets to solve the issue i.e. change `insert into tab1(header) values l_header;`  to `insert into tab1(header) values (l_header);`